# List of queries executed on mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql

Does mysql server keeps records of queries executed on it, if it  does so , is it possible to retrieve those queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html), which logs all queries in plain text.

We have this enabled on our development environment only. It shouldn't be a problem to turn this on temporarily on a production server during off-peak times.

If you're looking for slow queries, you may as well use the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: How did I miss the General Log? +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep record of all queries that are executed, you can enable either the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) or the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) and set the threshold to 0 seconds (any query that takes more than 0 seconds will be logged).

Another option is the [Binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html). However, binary log does not keep record of queries like `SELECT` or `SHOW` that do not modify data.

Note that these logs get pretty big pretty fast in a server with traffic. And that both might contain passwords so they have to be protected from unauthorized eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL Proxy which stands between client app and RDBMS itself.

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy

You can see online queries and also it allows you to rewrite queries based on rules.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option - use a profiler.

For instance: http://www.jetprofiler.com/